# Rails how to find record where the value is least?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table named Socks and it have a column named water (integer).

I want to find all records where the column water is at least `40`

Example if the water column is `400` the record would be found, but not if the value was `39`.

Answer (score 3):

Think the easiest thing to do would be to use the `where` method:

```
Sock.where("water >= ?", 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sock.where("water >= ?", 40).first
Sock.where("water >= ?", 40).last

to work on a specific model and not getting an array of models.